# How to evaluate the assembly Storage temperature?

Tags: temperature, storage

Question about the Storage Temperature after soldering in general.

If the components were all specified with, for example:

- Storage Temperature Tstg :  -65...+125°C;
- Operating Temperature (or Junction temperature, anyway) TJ :  -40...+85°C

**What shall we consider for specifying the storage temperature of their complete PCB assembly?**

For a simple start, let us assume:

- there are no CTE issues
- we are having very small components/semiconductors
- we are not cycling the environmental temperature

Answer (score 3):

Since, when in storage, the PCB does not operate, you can use the Storage Temperature range.

You do have to be sure that **everything** on the PCB meets the Storage Temperature Tstg : -65...+125°C range though. There only needs to be **one** component with a smaller Temperature Range and the complete PCB will then also have this smaller Storage Temperature range.

I would especially look at components like, batteries, (electrolytic) capacitors and (LCD) displays as these often have a smaller Storage Temperature range compared to resistors, ceramic capacitors, connectors and semiconductors (chips, transistors etc.).